# Why did Steve Rogers choose this character in Endgame?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ending, avengers-endgame

In the end of Endgame, we see Cap giving the shield to Sam Wilson.

So why didn't he give the shield to Bucky? Sam Wilson was already a great superhero without a shield, and Bucky obviously needed something more than a gun. Also, Steve and Bucky are best friends.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I approved the last edit, because it actually helps users to avoid spoilers.

Comment: Let's face it, There is nothing super about Sam other than his personality, now with the shield, he just became a bit more super

Comment: @Huangism I just can't imagine Captain America with mechanical wings.

Comment: Yea but think of the action sequence with flying cap. Or maybe he will fail to throw the shield like old cap since he does not have super strength

Comment: @Huangism Well, the vibranium is a very light material, so it's not a problem to throw the shield. Maybe Sam won't use the wings since he has the shield.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that this happened in the comics long before there was an MCU?

Comment: @IchabodE Did it? I thought Cap gave the shield to Bucky in the comics.

Comment: “Bucky obviously needed something more than a gun”. Um, he has a vibranium arm too.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211968/why-was-sam-wilson-chosen-for-this-but-not-bucky

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, I don't think a vibranium arm will help you much. Yes, it's strong, but it will help only in hand-to-hand combat.

Comment: @VerNick: Bucky deflects bullets with it in *Civil War*. It’s like a shield you can’t lose!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Huh? In the end of *Ciwil War* Stark simply rips Bucky's arm off :)

Comment: @VerNick: like anything, you can have it stolen from you by the capitalist imperialist dogs of profit!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Agree :D

Comment: @VerNick Google 'Sam Wilson Captain America'. In the comics Steve Rogers died, and SHIELD gave Sam the mantle and the shield.  But OF COURSE Steve came back.

Comment: @IchabodE [Bucky Becomes Captain America In The Comics, But The MCU May Have Other Plans](https://www.bustle.com/p/bucky-becomes-captain-america-in-the-comics-but-the-mcu-may-have-other-plans-17035467). 
It seems they were both given a shield at different times.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Although they are [Russo's words](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/102107/5315), I don't agree to their reasoning. I do, however, agree with their decision to pass on the symbol of Captain America to Sam.

Bucky is fighting for the right side now but that doesn't absolve him of the crimes he committed. Him being brainwashed doesn't erase his sins.

At the end of Civil War Bucky is still a criminal in the world. He has taken refuge in Wakanda and is healing. He doesn't leave Wakanda and fights with the Avengers and gets snapped. When he is blipped after 5 years and fights and wins with the Avengers saving humanity, however great his contribution may be, he still committed murder in his past and will be questioned as a criminal if not by law then by the media.

Bucky won't be an unquestioned symbol of integrity. His past and PTSD won't allow him to make the right decision at all times that is expected of Captain America.

Sam, on the other hand, fits the role perfectly. A retired war hero, who helps others with their PTSD, who got back into the field to help Captain America, when no one else would, was branded a fugitive and traitor, but did the right thing everytime no matter the personal cost.

He's the perfect candidate in terms of Steve because he sees himself in Sam.

He's the perfect candidate for the world, with unquestioned integrity.

Also, Steve had seen Bucky's mental and physical suffering and would rather let him rest and live out his days as a normal being. To get a life.

Comment: Your answer presents some excellent reasoning, but...isn't that pretty much what the Russos are saying, too? The answer still stands on its own, but I can't really see in which way it "disagrees with their reasoning".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson In the phrasing that *"not necessarily the guy that you would want to trust with another weapon because he can always be corrupted"*. I don't get the impression that he can be corrupted and possibly become menace to society if made CA. My reasoning is that he is a broken man, who doesn't have the moral conviction to make right choices for other people like Steve. Also, media would be instantly against him for his past. So, public opinion can go against him

Comment: I see. I guess I took the Russos' statement less direct and more in the way like you describe Bucky, too.

Comment: Yeah, I took the Russo's statement to be implying this, although your answer is good to expand on it. For the corruption, I assumed they meant he's also at risk of being further brainwashed as who knows what triggers still exist in him.

Answer (score 29):

Copying from [my answer to the same question on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211973/58193):

## Because Sam was the logical choice over Bucky

Joe Russo explains it in the following interview.

> "It made sense that it was Sam," Joe Russo said. "I don't think that there were significant debates at all. Bucky is portrayed in the films as very damaged, and not necessarily the guy that you would want to trust with another weapon because he can always be corrupted. And Sam, if anyone matches Cap's integrity over the course of the last few films, it's Sam. From the time that they met on the mall in D.C. through the end of this film, and he just seemed like the logical choice in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. We don't have all of the context that the comics have, we can only bring completion to the stories that we've been telling and that seemed to make the most sense."
>
> <sub>[Comic Book, Avengers: Endgame Directors Explain Why Captain America Chose Sam Over Bucky](https://comicbook.com/2019/05/06/avengers-endgame-directors-chose-sam-over-bucky-captain-america-replacement/)</sub>

Comment: "Bucky is portrayed in the films as very damaged, and not necessarily the guy that you would want to trust with another weapon because he can always be corrupted." - this isn't a great reason at all. Presumably, they were able to remove Bucky's conditioning in Wakanda, since he requested to be asleep until that happened. And such a statement that he's" damaged" is a pretty bad message about PTSD.

Comment: I think the angle they were going here is that Bucky undeniably has some darkness in him, and despite (presumably) being no longer affected by the conditioning, he's still been left somewhat damaged and cynical by the whole thing. Captain America (as a persona) is optimistic and never gives up ("I could do this all day"). Sam's outlook is definitely the closest to Cap's attitude to life. Plus, I can't help but spot the parallels between the post-Snap therapy session that Cap was running in Endgame, and the PTSD therapy session that Sam was running back in Winter Soldier. He's a natural choice.

Comment: they wanted a black cap

Comment: @Mithrandir: Bucky isn't damaged by PTSD. He's damaged by experimentation and brain-washing that turned him into one of Hydra's deadliest agents.